# why do we need router since switch can also use IP address

Tags: networking, router, modem, switch

If we use a switch to connect many hosts and inserted the IP addresses for all hosts, the switch still can connect between them, a modem is used to connect you to internet, it is said that router is used to connect multiple hosts to internet, but why is exactly a router used since a switch can already forward between many host among their IP's

Comment: I've given this a +1, as though you have a major misconception I think it may be worth someone detailing why it's a misconception. Wish you luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your modem includes a switch (many do) then it is a built in-router and possibly can do everything you need.

A plain modem without a built-in switch and related ports needs an additional router of your own. The router in this case will convert the External IP Address (of which you very most likely just have 1 External IP) to a range of Internal IP (usually 255 such internal addresses).

So minimally, you need:

(a) Modem: to connect to the outside world.

(b) Router: to convert (NAT) 1 External IP to multiple Internal IP addresses. A wireless router adds Wi-Fi capability.

(c) Switch: Only if you need extra LAN ports.

(a) and (b) are often combined and include Wi-Fi for regular consumer simplicity.

To your question above: A simple modem and a Switch alone cannot work because there is only 1 address (simple modem without router).

Comment: this is a bit of "home internet/network" explanation, while an overview networking explanation would be more like: "Switch --> A switch connects multiple computers and mobile devices together into a local network" and "Router --> A router connects separate networks, allowing information to route from one to the other" - as your home network is a local network, and the Internet is not, you need a router to connect the networks to be able to communicate to each other.

Comment: thank you guys, what made misconception is, in buildup home modem,router switch..the function of router is not clear, cuz you connect to internet via dsl port which is modem, you connect your lan via ethernet ports , while a router basically have wan ports, another idea is that a dial up modem connects you already to internet with no need to router